# How do I specify a redelivery policy and separate retry queue processor in Rebus

Tags: rebus

I'm currently investigating Rebus but being unable to find good documentation this process is proving difficult.  I am hoping someone can help me understand this exciting product.

[I have read](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Automatic-retries-and-error-handling) that during message processing, if something goes wrong the message will return to the queue.

1. Is the message returned to the front of the queue or placed on the end? If placed on the front this will be problem because the queue in essence becomes blocked with a message that may not be able to be processed - at least until it times out or retries exceeded.
2. Does Rebus have support for an out-of-the-box **[separate Retry queue](http://www.cogin.com/articles/SurvivingPoisonMessages.php#SeparateRetry)**?
3. Can I specify the interval between retries?
4. Can I specify an **exponential backoff** interval for retries as in [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The queue transaction is rolled back, effectively moving the message back in front - therefore, it will be immediately retried.

After 5 failed attempts (at least that is the default), Rebus will move the message to the error queue. The default retry mechanism is intentionally very swift - this way, the input queue will never be clogged by poisonous messages.

If you need more sophisticated retries, I suggest you tage a look at `bus.Defer` - it can defer delivery of a message to the future. It requires that you have a timeout manager(*) running though.

2) I guess that's what I call "error queue", except there's no retry :)

I did create a solution some time, though, where I coded a simple endpoint that would periodically empty the error queue and move all the messages back into the original source queue, as a form of crude automatic second-level retry mechanism.

3) No. NServiceBus has the concept of [second-level retries](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/second-level-retries), but this is something that I've never really needed (enough) with Rebus. But with Rebus, you're on your own here - it should be fairly easy to do some intelligent `bus.Defer` that can then be easily adapted to each kind of error that you're expecting.

4) See (3)

I hope that clarifies a bit :)

(*) The timeout manager can be a separate endpoint whose only job in life is to receive a message, hold on to it for a while (i.e. save it to a database), and then return it to the sender when the time has elapsed. The timeout manager can be hosted in-process though, but using the `.Timeouts(t => t.???)` configuration spell.